# Service Stack inject object

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack

i´m doing an app, using ServiceStack. I could inject an object without problems, but, the object can be modified outside the Service Class, so, i need to re inject again
Here is the code:

```
public class ClientManager: ApplicationContext{
   public ClientManager(AppConfig appConfig)
   {
        _appConfig = appConfig;
        _activeForm = LayoutFactory(appConfig.Layout);
        var appHost = new AppHost(_activeForm, _appConfig);
        var listeningOn = string.Format("http://*:{0}/", new Uri(appConfig.UrlBroker).Port);
        appHost.Init();
        appHost.Start(listeningOn);
        var timerMetadata = new Timer(CheckMetadata, null, 0, 60000);
    }
}

    public class AppHost : AppSelfHostBase
    {
        private ILayout _layout;
        private AppConfig _appConfig;
        public AppHost(ILayout activeForm, AppConfig appConfig)
        : base("ClientService", typeof(ClientService).Assembly)
    {
        _layout = activeForm;
        _appConfig = appConfig;
    }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        container.Register("activeForm", _layout);
        container.Register("config", _appConfig);

    }
}

    public class ClientService : Service
    {
        public HttpResult Post(Person request)
        {
           HttpResult response = new HttpResult();
            _initConf = ServiceStackHost.Instance.Container.ResolveNamed<AppConfig>("config");
        }
    }
```

So, the class ClientManager has a thread which can modify the object appConfig and activeForm (this objects are injected into the service class)
Now, if i modify the object, it doesn´t inject it again. I think thath i should dispose the AppHost, and start it again, what do you think?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very rare that you'd want to dispose the AppHost unless you're running Integration tests where you want to start/destroy multiple AppHost instances.

Also I'd strongly recommend against using names when registering dependencies, just use the types of the dependencies as normal, e.g:

```
container.Register(_layout);
container.Register(_appConfig);
```

Any dependencies registered in the IOC are then automatically injected into your Service class by declaring a **public property** with that type, e.g:

```
public class ClientService : Service
{
    public AppConfig AppConfig { get; set; }

    public HttpResult Post(Person request)
    {
       HttpResult response = new HttpResult();
       var _initConf = AppConfig;
    }
}
```

This injects the same instance that's registered in the IOC, so if you modify the instance later the Service would inject the same modified instance by default.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did it as you recommended. it still working fine (the object is injected into the service class). But, if I modify the object into the ClientManager class, in the service class i don´t see the object updated..

Comment: Don't see how that's possible, it has to inject the same instance, it can't create a new instance, it doesn't know how to. Are you sure you're modifying the instance and not just reassigning it cause that won't modify the instance.

Comment: Sorry, i was assigning wrong the data into the instance.. thanks!!